Is there a way to take back a `git add .` that still allows `git add --patch` afterwards?
I executed git add . by accident: I wanted to execute git add --patch instead because I know that I want my changes to go into three different commits.
I took back my mistaken git add . with git reset. git status then correctly listed all files waiting for being processed. However, git add --patch does not do anything.
I tried git rm -r  --cached instead of git reset, with exactly the same result.
I wonder whether this is a bug...
Update:
It has nothing to do with "reset" or "rm":
$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        file_1.md
        file_2.md
        file_3.md
        file_4.md

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

kai@mini MINGW64 /c/Buffer/aaa/repo_2 (main)
$ git add --patch
No changes.


Does git --patch usually do something? Do you mean git add --patch?

I did, tx for pointing this out, I've corrected it.

Does this answer your question? How to stage only part of a new file with git?

TL;DR: git add --intent-to-add file_1.md; git add --patch or short git add -N .; git add -p

The documentation for git add --patch says it

... effectively runs add --interactive, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand. See “Interactive mode” for details.

The documentation for "Interactive mode" describes add untracked, which is what you need to do, and which is an option in the top-level menu you explicitly skipped by using git add --patch.
If you want to control which parts of the new files are added to each commit, you can use git add -N to just start tracking them, and then add --patch as usual.

I misunderstood what --patch would do (it was my first attempt using it). What you pointed out explains the behaviour. I am disappointed regarding --patch, but thanks for the hint.

git add --patch never adds new (untracked) files. This isn’t related to the git reset (unless you already had both staged and unstaged changes); you need to git add the new files separately, e.g. git add file_1.md.
